# How to parse a large XML file by Oga in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml

I'm trying to parse a large XML file using Oga.
Until now, I was able to parse up to 1.5 Gb by the following script, but when I targeted a 5.6 Gb file, the memory used by Ruby became huge (over 50 Gb) and I could not get the parse result even in 3 days. 
I'm using MacOS 10.15.4, ruby 2.7.0, memory 16Gb.
I know there are other ways using different Gems including Nokogiri, but if possible I would like to know how to do it in Oga.

```
require 'oga'
Dir.chdir __dir__

file_n = "uniprot_sprot.xml"

xml = File.open(file_n)
puts "opened data file"
document = Oga.parse_xml(xml)
puts "parsed all data"

document.xpath('uniprot/entry').each do |entry|
  ...
end
```

Comment: have you tried the SAX parser of Oga?

Comment: How do I write the code?
I can not understand the difference and how to do it.
Please help me.

Comment: I'd like to know the code how .xpath iteration in SAX parsing.

Comment: You don't do xpath with SAX, you do evented. See my reply. If this helps, let us know about the performance, might be interesting.
If you need more infor probably i'd be good to paste a sample of XML as well as what you are doing with this XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the SAX style parser. Since SAX parsers don't create a document from the XML they are useful for parsing large documents. 
The drawback is that you will need to keep track of the state on your own. I've never used OGA for SAX parsing but I assume it will be suitable for your 5 GB XML.

Here is self contained example. Just paste it to a file and run it (the part after `__END__` will be available as input, in `DATA`).

```
require "oga"

class PeopleHandler
  PERSON_PATH = ["xml", "people", "person"]
  ATTRIBUTE_PATH = ["xml", "people", "person", "attribute"]
  attr_reader :people

  def initialize
    @people = []
    @current_person = nil
    @current_path = []
  end

  def on_element(_namespace, name, attrs = {})
    current_path.push(name)
    if current_path == PERSON_PATH
      people.push({id: attrs["id"]})
    elsif current_path == ATTRIBUTE_PATH
      people.last[attrs["name"]] = attrs["value"]
    end
  end

  def after_element(_namespace, name)
    current_path.pop
  end

  private

  attr_reader :current_path, :current_person
end

handler = PeopleHandler.new

Oga.sax_parse_xml(handler, DATA.read)

p handler.people

# [{:id=>"12", "first-name"=>"Pascal", "country"=>"Switzerland"}, {:id=>"13", "first-name"=>"Fred", "country"=>"Sweden"}, {:id=>"45", "first-name"=>"Karl", "country"=>"Hungary"}]

__END__
<xml>
  <people>
    <person id="12">
      <attribute name="first-name" value="Pascal" />
      <attribute name="country" value="Switzerland" />
    </person>
    <person id="13">
      <attribute name="first-name" value="Fred" />
      <attribute name="country" value="Sweden" />
    </person>
    <person id="45">
      <attribute name="first-name" value="Karl" />
      <attribute name="country" value="Hungary" />
    </person>
</xml>
```

Sax parsers work by emitting events to a handler. See a list of available events (methods that get called) here: https://github.com/YorickPeterse/oga/blob/master/lib/oga/xml/sax_parser.rb

The sample uses an array (`current_path`) to keep track of the position inside the document. Perhaps this is not required in your case and the element name is enough.

If a `<person>` element is reached I push a Hash to my list of people. Then for each `<attribute>` element I augment that hash (`people.last`) with some key/value pairs. After parsing is complete I have a list of people `handler.people` I can process further.

This is only to give you an example of how SAX parsers work.

- Perhaps you do not need to keep track of the path, perhaps the element name is good enough (i.e. when your element has an unique name). Then you can avoid keeping track of the position in an array.
- Maybe you do not want to build a collection of items to process further. It could be that you trade memory saved by using a SAX parser for memory you need for your items. Instead you might want to process an item once you have all the necessary information (probably in `after_element`) and then throw it away.

If you want to time different sections of your code you can use a simple solution:

Timing can be done pretty simple to get an idea:

```rb
t1 = Time.now
operation_1
t2 = Time.now
operation_2
t3 = Time.now
puts "Operation 1 took: #{t2 - t1}"
puts "Operation 2 took: #{t3 - t2}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
It's a very clear explanation.
I'll try to change my previous code to SAX parsing following your code and report the results.

Comment: Today, I run the code and get the result... It was very low memory consumption (probably near 600Mb...) and fast (80 min). 
I attached a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tkosaka1976/04929f984cc0e41ca255d127424ebbbd) describe the using code for UniProt XML parse to CSV.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Could you time how long parsing and how long writing the CSV took? Curious about that.
If it's fast enough, then probably no need to bother to speed it up? I guess there are some places to optimize. Is the source file publicly available?

Comment: It can be obtained from [an FTP site](ftp://ftp.uniprot.org/pub/databases/uniprot/current_release/knowledgebase/complete/uniprot_sprot.xml.gz).
I'm not sure how to measure the time need for parse and CSV writing.
I'm very glad if you show me the way.

Comment: I could not download the full XML file - perhaps because I'm on a flaky internet connection right now. WIll try again later.
Added info how to time to my answer.

Comment: FYI: i managed to download the XML and parse it. It spends seconds in CSV generation and the rest in XML parsing, so not worth it to optimize CSV part. 
If you want to speed this up, you might want to look at a different language or perhaps a different Ruby (i might try truffle ruby). If it is fast enough: don't bother.

Comment: Thank you, Pascal. Thank you for your report.
I don't have time to test the time required to parse XML by that code. But the script is executable for my purposes.
If you suffer from memory or time problems, I will remember your suggestion.